# Is there such a thing as an automatic variable resistor

Tags: resistors, variable

I have a skid steer loader that in ISO (for example, driving straight forward) with one joystick supplies on average 50 milliamps more power to the right forward solenoid coil than to the left coil causing the machine to steer to the left dramatically. The dealer has swapped out the computer and joystick control pods with no effect. I have hot wired the wiring loom to eliminate that as a problem and no luck. The dealer has abandoned the job. I have taken the machine to a Rexroth specialist who tells me there is nothing wrong with the hydraulics and the problem is the electronics, so back to my original question.

Is there such a thing that can be installed between the computer and the coil that can take an input of say 500 milliamps and output 550 all the way up to 1.100 milliamps and output 1.140 or can the power to the other coil be reduced by 50 milliamps to achieve the same outcome? Bobcat Skid Steers have software to eliminate this problem, but Case skid steers don't.

---

The wheel motors start to turn at 560mA and as you push the joystick forward it increases the current gradually through to full speed at 1160mA.

The reason I have put this question up is that I am a skid steer operator who can wire up a light but I have no idea about electronics.  If I were to fit a resistor in series with the solenoid coil would that work through the range from 560-1160 so instead of 560mA it would be 510mA and at 850mA it would be 800mA?

Skid steer machines have one drive motor on each side of the machine, one drive motor is connected by chain to both wheels on the left of the machine and the other drive motor drives the wheels on the right side of the machine.
There are two operating standards

- ISO uses one joystick to drive both wheel motors
- H pattern uses the left joystick to operate the left side wheels and the right joystick to operate the right side wheels,

The machine works perfectly in reverse and I have swapped the coils around to assess if the coil could be an issue but it does not appear to be.

A youtube video of what is happening is [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ijfLv6YMRg&t=32s)

Comment: Can you just put a resistor in parallel with the solenoid coil to absorb 50mA of current?
Is it a voltage control or current control?
What's the voltage on the coil?

Comment: Generally speaking, it will be far easier to reduce the drive to the solenoid getting more current than to increase the drive to the one getting less.

Comment: For anyone wondering, "skid-steer" is used on some building-site machinery, typically with a front loader bucket. None of the four wheels are steerable but the machine is turned similarly to a tank by driving the wheels on each side at different speeds. I don't know what ISO is.

Comment: _"the dealer has swapped out the computer and joystick control pods with no effect, , I have hot wired the wiring loom to eliminate that as a problem and no luck... tells me there is nothing wrong with the hydraulics and the problem is the electronics"_ - so if it's not the electronics, wiring or hydraulics then what's left? Have the solenoids been tested to verify equal resistance and inductance?

Comment: As a side comment I wouldn't even think of messing up with a control system which may kill someone in case of sudden failure. I also believe it's mostly illegal worldwide.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the repair of construction equipment.  While electronic design is vaguely alluded to, there is insufficient knowledge and containment of the overall system problem to make this an on topic electronic design problem.  Trying to fake out one apparent analog computer with another sounds rather dodgy.

Comment: People always blame the electronics when faults are mechanical. Sure the electronics can compensate for a mechanical fault, but do you want that? What if there is a pressure leak or debris in the system?

Comment: Despite other comments re the problem being mechanical I think it looks electrical. The video showing the two meters with different readings seems conclusive IF that it pushing the joystick 'up the centre'. If you dealer sees that happen how do they explain it? There is something in the joystick control circuitry that produces an imbalance in current. Either the joystick pots are faulty or the electronics that convert pot value to current or just maybe the load (solenoid). The dealer MUST be able to make the system produce balanced current or there are problems with their competence.

Comment: I've added your 'answer' into your question. Please edit as required.

Answer (score 1):

Measure both coil resistances. And the joystick voltage. With that known it may be possible to work out how to trim out the error.

Based on your current question it sounds like a 50mA constant current sink could be a quick and dirty solution. However i am left suspecting its a voltage driven joystick. And the resistance is lower on 1 coil

Having measured both coils if you find there is a difference. Then adding series resistance to match it back up may resolve your issue. Otherwise with that information it may be possible to design a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. I've been designing firmware for these kind of applications and also been involved in modding a few Bobcats.

First of all, the electrical servos/solenoid coils will not have super-accurate resistance. The coil resistance will vary *a lot* depending on temperature, and not necessarily in a linear manner. Where each coil is placed physically will affect thermal characteristics a lot, such as ability to cool down.
So measuring resistance manually with an ohm meter on a cold machine and then applying Ohm's law is nonsense. All that matters is the live output current.

The control system will need to measure the current and regulate it accordingly. It will also need to calibrate the minimum-maximum currents per function. The currents you mention 600mA-1200mA are pretty much industry standard for 12V systems, but you might have individual variations and cables, connectors etc also affect it slightly. The relevant minimum current is the one where the function begins to move.

Each proportional function is otherwise fairly linear. The control system needs to translate the linear joystick function into the individual linear current per proportional function. Furthermore it may need to apply a "dither"/"chopper" frequency PWM to prevent a "ketchup effect" when activating it.

Summary: you need a somewhat advanced control system for this, not just some "variable resistor".

The 50mA offset you measure might most likely be intentionally caused by the control system - perhaps it has been incorrectly calibrated? Or it may as well be an issue with the joystick.

Answer (score 0):

Despite other comments re the problem being mechanical I think it looks electrical.
Your video showing the two meters with different readings seems conclusive IF that happens while pushing the joystick 'up the centre'.

If your dealer sees that happen how do they explain it? - or rather how do they not see it as a clear electrical error?

There is something in the joystick control circuitry that produces an imbalance in current. Either the joystick pots are faulty or the electronics that convert pot value to current or the load (solenoid) and/or its power supply.

The dealer MUST be able to make the system produce balanced current or there are problems with their competence.